# Is there any command to display active Ethernet connection name?

Tags: cmd, wifi, ethernet, ssid

I need to display connected Ethernet name.

I used the following command to get WLAN connected network (Wi-Fi).

```
C:\Users\User>netsh wlan show interface | findstr /i "SSID"  name
    SSID                   : HOME
    BSSID                  : bc:62:d2:4a:a1:48
```

[image: Windows 10 network display with connected Wi-Fi network with name HOME]

An error message is output if I run the following command next:

```
C:\Users\User>netsh lan show interface command

The Wired AutoConfig Service (dot3svc) is not running.
```

But after I started the service, I still do not get the active connected Ethernet name.

```
C:\Users\User>netsh lan show interface command

There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name             : Ethernet
    Description      : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
    GUID             : e901d916-86f4-4070-9941-47a9a325537a
    Physical Address : 98-E7-43-0F-8F-84
    State            : Connected. Network does not support authentication.
```

[image: Windows 10 network display with connected wired LAN network with name Home]

Can anyone help me to get the Ethernet name `Home` on wired LAN connection?

Comment: Please also try showing the `profiles` and instead of the `interfaces`. `%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe LAN Show Profiles`.

Comment: Does this help? [`wmic`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)`NIC get AdapterType,AdapterTypeId,Caption,DeviceID,Name,NetConnectionID,NetConnectionStatus,NetEnabled,PhysicalAdapter /VALUE`

Comment: @Compo When i use profiles, i got only these details not the name of the connected network!!

C:\WINDOWS\system32>%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe LAN Show Profiles

    Profile Version        : 1
    Type                   : Wired LAN
    AutoConfig Version     : 1
    802.1x                 : Enabled
    802.1x                 : Not Enforced
    EAP type               : Microsoft: Protected EAP (PEAP)
    802.1X auth credential : [Profile credential not valid]
    Cache user information : [Yes]

Machine profile is not installed on this device.

Comment: @aschipfl Nope! It doesn't provide connected network name. its showing only adapter properties & details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command, entered directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), should display the name of the connected network profile(s), regardless of whether they are wired or wireless, on a Windows 8 / Server 2012 Operating System or newer.

```sh
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /NameSpace:\\Root\StandardCimv2 Path MSFT_NetConnectionProfile Where "IPv4Connectivity='4'" Get Name /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %G
```

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), for GUI double-click, it would look a little more like this:

```sh
@(For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 /NameSpace:\\Root\StandardCimv2 Path MSFT_NetConnectionProfile Where
 "IPv4Connectivity='4'" Get Name /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%G) & Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `netsh lan` You are querying wired *(Ethernet)* interface.
What you want is the wireless one. For that, just use :
`netsh wlan`
**wlan** stand for *Wireless Lan.*

Comment: No, they specifically asked about the ethernet connection name